# python3 - thread is missing from enumerate result when it is sleeping

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sleep

We have an API endpoint that starts a thread, and another endpoint to check the status of the thread (based on a thread ID returned by the first API call).
We use the threading module.

The function that the thread is executing may or may not sleep for a duration of time.

When we create the thread, we override the default name provided by the module and add the thread ID that was generated by us (so we can keep track).

The status endpoint gets the thread ID from the client request and simply loops over the results from `threading.enumerate()`. When the thread is running and not sleeping, we see that the thread is returned by the `threading.enumerate()` function. When it is sleeping, it is not.

The function we use to see if a thread is alive:

```
def thread_is_running(thread_id):
    all_threads = [ t.getName() for t in threading.enumerate() ]
    return any(thread_id in item for item in all_threads)
```

When we run in debug and print the value of "all_threads", we only see the MainThread thread during our thread's sleep time.
As soon as the sleep is over, we see our thread in the value of "all_threads".

This is how we start the thread:

```
thread_id = random.randint(10000, 50000)
thread_name = f"{service_name}-{thread_id}"
threading.Thread(target=drain, args=(service_name, params,), name=thread_name).start()
```

Is there a way to get a list of all threads including idle threads? Is a sleeping thread marked as idle? Is there a better way to pause a thread?

We thought about making the thread update it's state in a database, but due to some internal issue we currently have, we cannot 100% count on writing to our database, so we prefer checking the system for the thread's status.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason we did not see the thread was our use of gunicorn and multi workers.

The thread was initiated on one of the 4 configured workers while the status api call could've been handled by any of the 4 workers. only when it was handled by the worker who is also responsible of running the thread - we were able to see it in the enumerate output

Comment: how you can able to solve this , i am also using multi worker and having same issue.

Comment: We had 2 options:
1. decrease the amount of workers to 1
2. create another thread that will monitor the first thread (that is actually doing the job). the second thread (we called it heart beat thread) will update a db table one each successfull check of the first thread. if the db table is not getting updates for X amount of time or if the heart beat thread updated the db table that the first thread completed/died - we would know both threads status.